# in php, How can I extract a JSON from an array?

Tags: php, json, symfony, web

I'm receiving a string from the database and I only want to use the JSON so I can use a json_decode on it.

this is the string:

array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { ["reporte_id"]=> int(1) ["tabla_id"]=> int(1) ["configuracion"]=> string(1000) "{"tabla":"servtp","config":[{"name":"Client","type":"smallint","notnull":"0","pk":"0"},{"name":"Distribuidor_","type":"varchar(40)","notnull":"0","pk":"0"},{"name":"Branch","type":"smallint","notnull":"0","pk":"0"},{"name":"Cve","type":"smallint","notnull":"0","pk":"0"},{"name":"FechaApertura","type":"date","notnull":"0","pk":"0"},{"name":"FechaFactura","type":"date","notnull":"0","pk":"0"},{"name":"Dias","type":"smallint","notnull":"0","pk":"0"},{"name":"WorkingDays","type":"real","notnull":"0","pk":"0"},{"name":"Mes_","type":"smallint","notnull":"0","pk":"0"},{"name":"NumeroOT","type":"varchar(10)","notnull":"0","pk":"0"},{"name":"VentasNetas_","type":"real","notnull":"0","pk":"0"},{"name":"TipoOrden","type":"varchar(30)","notnull":"0","pk":"0"},{"name":"Type","type":"varchar(3)","notnull":"0","pk":"0"},{"name":"Taller","type":"varchar(30)","notnull":"0","pk":"0"},{"name":"Clasificacion_","type":"varchar(16)","notnull":"0","pk":"0"},{"name":"Retencion_","type":"varchar(1)","notnull":" ["nom_reporte"]=> string(33) "Monthly Service Operation Report " } }

Comment: That's still simple array traversal. What have you tried?

Comment: Is that whole string literally what you want to use, or is it the value under the "configuracion" (or some other) key?

Comment: is the "configuracion" what i want to use, i need to extract that JSON, i'm receiving that from the database.

Comment: I haven't tried a single thing since I don't know how to extract that JSON :(

Comment: $conn = $this->get('conexion');
        $sql = "SELECT tr.reporte_id, tr.tabla_id, t.configuracion, r.nom_reporte
        FROM tabla_reporte AS tr
       JOIN tabla as 
           ON tr.tabla_id = t.id
       JOIN reporte as r
           ON tr.reporte_id = r.id
        WHERE reporte_id = 1
           AND tabla_id = 1";
        $archivo = $conn
            ->executeQuery($sql)
            ->getResult();
        // Json
        var_dump($archivo);
        return $archivo;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the variable is called $variable, ... you have to:

```
$json = $archivio[0]['configuration'];
$arrayConf = json_decode($json);
```

Comment: this is what i'm doing....                     

$conn = $this->get('conexion'); $sql = "SELECT tr.reporte_id, tr.tabla_id, t.configuracion, r.nom_reporte FROM tabla_reporte AS tr JOIN tabla as ON tr.tabla_id = t.id JOIN reporte as r ON tr.reporte_id = r.id WHERE reporte_id = 1 AND tabla_id = 1"; $archivo = $conn ->executeQuery($sql) ->getResult(); Json var_dump($archivo); return $archivo;

Answer (score 1):

The string you are presenting is a var_dump of a php array, it is not properly formed.  Where you are getting that string from should fix their side to properly format the array formatting.

Comment: This is what I'm doing...

$conn = $this->get('conexion'); $sql = "SELECT tr.reporte_id, tr.tabla_id, t.configuracion, r.nom_reporte FROM tabla_reporte AS tr JOIN tabla as t ON tr.tabla_id = t.id JOIN reporte as r ON tr.reporte_id = r.id WHERE reporte_id = 1 AND tabla_id = 1"; $archivo = $conn ->executeQuery($sql) ->getResult(); // Json var_dump($archivo); // return array('data' => ['La', 'Le', 'Li']); return $archivo;

Comment: Are you working with a Symfony model?  If so lookup how to serialize to json.  I'm not famaliar with symfony so I can't tell you how to do it exactly.